# Why Can't I Delete Files With A Tilde?

Tags: windows, file-io, erlang, elixir

Elixir 1.3.2

Erlang/OTP 19

Windows 7 (Standard User and Administrator)

I'm trying to hack together a small Elixir script to wrap around commiting files to git.  The first thing I do, in order to insure I don't accidentally stage temporary files created by emacs is File.rm("*~").  However, this is what I get:

```
iex(2)> File.rm("*~")
{:error, :eio}
```

So I tried `File.rm("*.*~")`.  Same result. I get the same behavior when I run as either a Standard User (which is how I normally work on Windows) or as an administrator so it doesn't seem to be anything with permissions either.

So I captured the files into a list.

```
iex(15)> {:ok,files} = File.ls
{:ok,
 [".git", ".gitattributes", ".gitignore", "add.factor", "async_ut",
  "async_ut.cs", "cng_maint", "codecvg.cmd", "codecvg_rkt.cmd",
  "codecvg_rkt.cmd~", "CreateBr.vbs", "DevSandbox", "distillery", "dk.cmd",
  "example.scm", "example.sql", "factor", "fsele", "fsharp", "glp.vbs",
  "lwwtww.org", "mrgmain.cmd", "MrgMain.vbs", "mrgtrunk.cmd", "mrgtrunk.cmd~",
```

(truncated to save space)

I can check for the strings in the list containing `~` and it comes back true.  So I'm not imagining the tilde being there.

I created a temporary file called `test.txt` in the directory.  `File.rm` removed that one just fine so it seems to be something about the `~` which is causing the issue. I also tried these:

```
iex(7)> File.rm("*\~")
{:error, :eio}
iex(8)> File.rm("*\7F") #7F is hex code of ~
{:error, :eio}
```

No luck as you can see.

Googling for anything about `:eio` with Elixir and File.rm didn't turn up anything helpful.  I can try installing 1.4.0 to see if that has an effect but I just wanted to see if I was missing something dumb and obvious here.

I've also got cygwin on the machine so I tried removing the files that way.  `rm *~` worked exactly as expected (under a standard user).

It seems as if this is somehow an Erlang specific issue but I'm aksing here first. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: How about `Path.wildcard("*~") |> Enum.each(&File.rm/1)`? `*` won't be expanded by `File.rm/1`.

Comment: Hmm.  Didn't realize that File.rm wouldn't expand the wildcard.  Is that documented somewhere and I missed it when I was researching it?

Comment: Well, I would consider not documented meaning it won't be expanded.

Comment: I guess that could be implied, yes.  I just assumed that it could handle a wildcard since it seemed to be a wrapper around the OS' rm command.

Comment: Unix's `rm` also does not expand wildcards. I'm not sure about Windows.

Comment: Really?  I tried `rm *~` on Cygwin and it worked just fine--which is why I thought rm would expand a wildcard.

Comment: That's the shell expanding the wildcard before calling `rm`. Try `rm "*~"` and it'll try to delete the file literally named `*~`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[File.rm/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#rm/1) won't process wildcards automatically as far as I know, you need to use the [`Path.wildcard/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Path.html#wildcard/2) function:

```
File.rm(Path.wildcard("*~"))
```

or

```
Path.wildcard('*~') |> Enum.each(fn x -> File.rm(x) end)
```

for more than one file (which is probably the more general case).

Comment: Should those be single quotes on your second code fragment (in the `Path.wildcard` argument i mean)?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci You might need double quotes on Windows, on Linux/OS X the single quotes worked.

Comment: Do you not know the difference between single quotes and double quotes on Elixir?  http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#char-lists

Comment: The double quotes I was talking about were for the Windows shell, not for anything Elixir specific.

Answer (score 1):

On the Unix command line, `rm` will be called by the shell - and the shell is responsible for wildcard expansion, variable interpolation, etcetera before the actual command is called. So strictly speaking, Unix `rm` does not support wildcards either - it's the shell that does; `rm` just loops through its arguments and calls the `unlink()` system call on each of them. The Erlang library mimics this behaviour.

(On Windows, the shell does not do wildcard expansion, at least not the classic shell - I don't know about PowerShell. Commands have to do this themselves, which is hugely annoying when writing command line utilities. At least, this was the state of the art when I dabbled in Windows ;-))