# Elixir shell command with wildcard failing when using System.cmd

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an elixir program that needs to programmatically delete a variable amount of PNG files named as such.

```
/path/to/dir/<uuid>-frames-001.png
/path/to/dir/<uuid>-frames-002.png
/path/to/dir/<uuid>-frames-003.png
```

etc.

Naturally, I have come up with the following elixir code to delete these files.

```
System.cmd("rm", ["/path/to/dir/" <> uuid <> "-frames-*.png"])
```

I have seen the above code fail in multiple ways. First off, I have run it on server and seen the following stacktrace:

```
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/path/to/dir/<uuid>-frames-*.png': No such file or directory
```

I have also run this code on a console session and seen the exact same output.

If I run the following command in a bash session, it works fine!

`rm /path/to/dir/<uuid>-frames-*.png`

It returns a `0` error code and it deletes the expected files. It seems like elixir is interpreting the `*` as a literal character, and not performing the expected wildcard delete. Any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks!

P.S.

Obviously, `<uuid>` is an actual uuid and therefore should not be interpreted literally for the scope of this problem.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285984/why-cant-i-delete-files-with-a-tilde

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wildcards like `*` are expanded by the shell, not by `rm`. Your command will only delete the file literally called `/path/to/dir/<uuid>-frames-*.png`.

You can make the wildcard expand by passing the command to a shell like `sh`:

```
System.cmd("/bin/sh", ["-c", "rm /path/to/dir/#{uuid}-frames-*.png"])
```

or use `os:cmd/1` which by default invokes `sh` (note the single quotes instead of double):

```
:os.cmd('rm /path/to/dir/#{uuid}-frames-*.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

The *path* in the second argument in call to [`System.cmd/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/2) “a list of binaries which the executable will receive as its arguments *as is*.” From [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3):

> This means that:
>
> — environment variables will not be interpolated
> — **wildcard expansion will not happen** (unless [`Path.wildcard/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Path.html#wildcard/2) is used explicitly)
> — arguments do not need to be escaped or quoted for shell safety.

So, to wildcard to work, one should:

```
System.cmd("rm", Path.wildcard("/path/to/dir/" <> uuid <> "-frames-*.png"))
```

Note, that since `Path.wildcard/2` already returns a list, it should not be wrapped again.

There are many other workarounds, but for this particular case just use [`File.rm/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#rm/1).

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding Path.wildcard. Can you elaborate on your comment about using `File.rm/1` "for this particular case"? File.rm does not expand wildcards, so what was your strategy there?